# What is wrong in Angular2 ng-if

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm really new to angular, I have been through all ng-if questions and cannot seem to find the right answer.

I have this:

```
<tr *ngFor="#position of positions">                               
<td>
 <div ng-if="position.way == 0">Long</div>
 <div ng-if="position.way == 1">Short</div>
 {{position.way}}
 </td>
</tr>
```

{{position.way}} is outputting either 1 or 0 as expected and is defined as a string in the model. But the two div's are both displayed no matter what position.way is.

I have tried wrapping 0 and 1 in quotes, I have tried tripple equality operator, same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ng-if` syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
<tr *ngFor="let position of positions">                               
<td>
 <div *ngIf="position.way == 0">Long</div>
 <div *ngIf="position.way == 1">Short</div>
 {{position.way}}
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks! I guess I was finding angular1 code when searching for this.

Comment: `ng-if` was a thing in Angular2 as well a while back but was changed https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha52-2015-12-10 when case-sensitive templates were introduced.

Comment: How could `position` be undefined here, since it's always defined for each  loop iteration, right?

Comment: Right of course. Didn't pay attention. Thanks for the hint!